# copy files from master to new branch

Tags: git, github

I have been working on a project for a customer. The customer is now asking me to upload the stuff I am working on their github account. I dont want to change their setup, I would like to create a new branch. On my local machine I have done the following. When I do a git status I get that working tree is clean. How can I push all the files from master to devBranch to be able to upload just this branch and not interfere with the customer's master branch?

```
git add.
git branch dev_branch
git checkout dev_branch
```

Comment: Git does not deal in "files". It deals in "commits". Every commit represents the entire state of your work on your project. Please express what you want to do in terms of commits. So, if you already have been using Git and you already have commits, talk about what you want to do with them. Thanks. Oh, also, have you already been pushing to this remote (the customer)? Or to some other remote (your own GitHub account)? Thanks again.

Comment: This is the first time I will be pushing stuff to them.  I dont want to overwrite their master branch.  I have created an initial commit on the master with all the files.  Now I need to copy all the stuff over from the master branch to be able to push everything customers github account.

Comment: So just make and checkout this new branch and push it. It looks like you've done the make-and-checkout part, so now just push `dev_branch` to their remote.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a [`git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) in your sequence.

The usual way is:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git switch -c new_branch master
# work
git add .
git commit -m "New work on new branch"
git push -u origin new_branch
```

If you don't have the right to push back to the original repository, then you would need [to fork it first](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo).

Comment: Except maybe not `origin`, we have not been able to get the OP to describe the remote situation.

Comment: @matt True, I was assuming the OP cloned the remote repo and was part of the collaborators allowed to push back to it, hence the new to not override/change master. That is... a lot of assumptions!

Comment: Yeah, I'm assuming something quite different. :)